# correlations between questionnaires/ variables

Tags: r, correlation

I am working with different questionnaires. In example I have agroup of participqants who only needed to fill in 3 questionnaires, others who had to fill in 4, others 6, and other 7. I want to evaluate their quality of life over time, however some particpipants filled in all their questionnaires on the same day (I realize that this introduces a big bias in my analysis). Now I want to check whether the questionnaires that were filled on the same day if they are also filled the same way for each questionnaire. Here is an example:

```
id QA1 QA2 QA3 QA4 QA5 QA6 QB1 QB2 QB3 QB4 QB5 QB6
1   1   3    2   2  3   3   1   3    2   2  3   3
2   2   NA    2   2  2  1   1   3    2   1  2   3 
3   3   2    3   1  1   1   2   1    1   NA 3  NA 
4   2   1    NA  3  2   NA  1   3    3   1  2   1 
5   1   1    3   2  1   3   1   1    3   2  1   3
```

In the example id 1 and 5 filled in both questionnaires the same way. How can I check this for my complete dataframe?

Regards

Comment: what do you mean in the same way? id's 1 and 5 have different values for QA2, QA3, QA5, QB2, QB3, QB4, and QB5...is it simply because they both dont contain NA? Also your example is not reproducible. please use ``dput()``

Comment: I mean that they contain the same values. QA is one questionnaire and QB is another, they are given on different days but conitain more or less the same questions. For id1 i.e. QA1=1 and QB1=1, QA2=3 and QB2=3.etc for the complete questionnaire

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: Yes but how do I copy it once I dput() it?

Comment: " In example I have agroup of participqants who only needed to fill in 3 questionnaires, others who had to fill in 4, others 6, and other 7" ... where is this shown in the example?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem. It checks each row and compares the response values:

```
QAs <- grep('QA', colnames(df)) #which cols contain QA survey questions
QBs <- grep('QB', colnames(df)) #which cols contain QB survey questions
#check if all non-NA values are the same and all NAs are in same location. 
check <- function(x){
    return( all(all(x[QAs] == x[QBs], na.rm=T), all(is.na(x[QAs]) == is.na(x[QBs])) ) ) 
}
apply(df, 1, check)

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```